# How to get the average of many times every user has given a solution (query)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Suppose I have these table:

**user**: id

**problem**: id

**solution**: id, user_id, problem_id

How do I get the number of times each user has solved each problem?

I need something like this in my result set:

```
user_id  problem_id  times
-------  ----------  -----
1        1           3
1        2           4
2        2           8
2        3           1
```

And then I need the average of the time each problem was solved:

```
problem_id  avg
----------  ---
1           3
2           6
3           1
```

I think it is something like:

```
SELECT problem_id, avg(times) as avg from
       (SELECT user_id, problem_id, count(*) as times FROM solution
               group by user_id) sample
       group by problem_id;
```

But the result set doesn't look right. I don't know...

Comment: You need `GROUP BY user_id, problem_id` in your inner query.

Comment: Do you require the mode, median or mean for the average?

Answer (score 0):

The following query will give you the results specified in the first table

```
SELECT 
    user_id
    , problem_id
    , COUNT(*) AS times
FROM
    solution
GROUP BY
    user_id
    , problem_id
```

The second query to me seems a little odd, it seems you are getting the average number of times a user has answered that question type (but it's not my place to judge your requirements). As previously stated your query was almost there, it should have given you an error warning regarding the arguments provided in the `GROUP BY` clause not including all returned columns not included in aggregate functions.

```
SELECT 
    problem_id
    , AVG(times) AS avg 
FROM
    (  SELECT 
           user_id
           , problem_id
           , COUNT(*) AS times
       FROM
            solution
       GROUP BY
           user_id
           , problem_id
    ) userCounts
GROUP BY 
    problem_id;
```

Alternatively if you want to avoid sub-queries something along the lines of the following should work:

```
SELECT 
    problem_id
    , (COUNT(DISTINCT id) / COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)) AS avg 
FROM
    solution
GROUP BY 
    problem_id;
```

The above queries are all demonstrated in the following [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7dbc0/1)